# Calling method on C++ singleton object in JS yields "TypeError: Property 'foo' of object [object Object] is not a function"

Tags: c++, qt, import, singleton, qml

I'm registering a C++ class as a QML singleton, and attempting to call a method on this singleton from JS. I'm getting this error message:

> TypeError: Property 'readAll' of object [object Object] is not a function

My code:

*main.cpp* (just registers a singleton, done by the books):

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "fileio.h"

static QObject* fileIOSingletonTypeProvider(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
{
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)

    FileIO* example = new FileIO();
    return example;
}

static void registerQmlTypes()
{
    qmlRegisterSingletonType<FileIO>("FileIO", 1, 0, "FileIO", fileIOSingletonTypeProvider);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    registerQmlTypes();
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

*fileio.cpp*:

```
#include "fileio.h"

FileIO::FileIO(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void FileIO::readAll()
{
}
```

*fileio.h*:

```
#ifndef FILEIO_H
#define FILEIO_H

#include <QObject>

class FileIO : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FileIO(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE void readAll();
};

#endif // FILEIO_H
```

*main.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import "test.js" as Code

Window {
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        Code.func();
    }
}
```

*test.js*:

```
.import FileIO 1.0 as FileIO

function func() {
    FileIO.readAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer [here](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2015-May/016932.html). Although they refer to importing from QML and I refer to importing from JS, the solution is the same, namely:

Either call the method as `FileIO.FileIO.readAll()` or remove the `as FileIO` from the `.import` statement.

This is not at all apparent from the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html#importing-a-qml-module-from-a-javascript-resource) which neither mention the need to double the `FileIO` qualifier, nor mention the possibility to remove the `as FileIO`. I've [reported a documentation bug to Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTWEBSITE-735).

Comment: The first `FileIO` is the name you specified at import, basically a namespace.
I.e. once you tell the engine to use such a namespace, it needs to be used to address its contents.
Just like in C++, so that's likely why it is not explicitly documented.